# Setting celery concurrency to 1 worker per queue

Tags: concurrency, rabbitmq, celery

I am essentially using rabbitmq queues in celery as a poor man's synchronisation.  Eg when certain objects are updated (and have a high cost), I round robin them to a set of 10 queues based on their object IDs.  Firstly is this a common pattern or is there a better way.

Secondly, with celeryd, it seems that the concurrency level option (CELERY_CONCURRENCY) sets the number of workers across all the queues.  This kind of defeats the purpose of using the queues for synchronization as a queue can be serviced by multiple workers, which means potential race conditions when performing different actions on the same object.

Is there a way to set the concurrency level (or worker pool options) so that we have one worker per N queues?

Thanks
Sri

Comment: To add to that, I would like to avoid the option of having multiple celeryd instances running with different configs (ie each one set to CELERY_CONCURRENCY = 1 and listening to only a subset of the 10 queues).  If this is the only way then bummer.

Answer (score 2):

Why you don't simply implements a global task lock system, by using memcache or a nosql db?
In this way you avoid any race condition.

Here an example
http://ask.github.com/celery/cookbook/tasks.html#ensuring-a-task-is-only-executed-one-at-a-time

Comment: Hey Mauro, pretty good example.  thanks for that.  But a couple of questions:

    1. Wouldnt this essentially leave the worker idle while the lock hasnt been released by another thread?  I could increase the number of threads but it doesnt really solve the problem does it.  

    2. I can see this extending to requiring multiple locks across the system which means added complexity or rising deadlocks.

    3. Finally I wanted to avoid an external dependancy just to get concurrency right.  I can see general use for memcache but just for this seems a long one.

Comment: Basically you can do what you want when you found a lock, you can implement your own behavior, you can retry the task or let him fail that the works can continue to receive other tasks.
basically what you have to do is to create a base class for your tasks that extend celery.task and override the __call__ methods and the after_return methods. In this way you don't have to write the lock behavior in each task logic. Check out the slide number 21-22 of this presentation http://www.slideshare.net/fireantology/europython-2011-playing-tasks-with-django-celery the comments character are not enough

Answer (score 0):

Related to the first part of your question, I've asked and answered a similar question here: [Route to worker depending on result in Celery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705833/route-to-worker-depending-on-result-in-celery/19904836#19904836)

Essentially you can route directly to a worker depending on a key, which in your case is an ID. It avoids any need for a single locking point. Hopefully it's useful, even though this question is 2 years old :)